# How to set parent view's height based on subview's height

Tags: react-native

I want to write a customized parent `View` which includes either one `Text` componet subView or two `Text` component subViews. Is there a way to set the parent `View`'s height based on the `Text` view's height?

```
class ParentView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      titleText,
      bodyText,
    } = this.props;

    //if titleText is passed to props, measure it's height; 
    //if bodyText is passed to props, measure it's height;
    // set contentContainer height = titleText + bodyText + someMargin
    return (
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>        
        {titleText && <Text style={styles.title}>
          {titleText}
        </Text>}
        {bodyText && <Text style={styles.body}>
          {bodyText}
        </Text>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you need to set parent's height at all? You can simple omit height, min/max and flex styles so parent will wrap its children.

Comment: Have you tried any of the given answers?

Answer (score 16):

You can set `flex:0` on your `View` container

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 0
  }
});
```

with this way it will expand according to the children height.

A few info about `flex` property:

> When flex is a positive number, it makes the component flexible and it
>   will be sized proportional to its flex value. So a component with flex
>   set to 2 will take twice the space as a component with flex set to 1.
>
> When flex is 0, the component is sized according to width and height
>   and it is inflexible.
>
> When flex is -1, the component is normally sized according width and
>   height. However, if there's not enough space, the component will
>   shrink to its minWidth and minHeight.

Comment: Thanks about `flex:0`. It's saves my life :v

Comment: I can't thank you enough. You're a genius!