# How to change a height view dynamically in react native?

Tags: react-native, view

I got a simple view that contains text:

```
            <View style = {styles.container}>                    
                <Text style = {styles.bla}>{blablabla}</Text>
            </View>  

 container:{
marginTop: 15,
marginRight: 15,
marginLeft: 15,
flexDirection:"row",
flex:1,
borderWidth: 1,
borderRadius: 2,
borderColor: '#ddd',
borderBottomWidth: 0,    
elevation: 2,
```

},

The text rows will vary, so that's why I want my view to change its height depending on the text inside it.

I already tried `aspectRatio`, it doesn't work

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041183/how-to-set-parent-views-height-based-on-subviews-height

Comment: I tried. It didn't work as well. I mean, I lose the scrollview that wraps my view and the borderBottom.

Answer (score 0):

I  finally figured it out by wrapping my view in another view.